# Dois campos num picker - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

É possível ter 2 campos num `Picker`? Hoje tenho uma listagem de Categoria e gostaria de poder colocar o Código da Categoria na frente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código XAML do `Picker`:

```
               <Picker x:Name="pckCategoria"
                        Title="Selecione uma Categoria"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CATEGORIA}"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Margin="10, 0, 10, 0">
                </Picker>
```

Caso não seja possível trazer os dois conteúdos no `picker` eu posso simplesmente receber o Código da Categoria quando uma Categoria for selecionada também, já seria uma saída, mas até agora não consegui fazer, já vi muito conteúdo mas nenhum conseguiu me atender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção seria criar uma propriedade que mesclasse os dois conteúdos, por exemplo, o objeto teria três propriedades:
1-Código
2-Categoria
3-CategoriaCódigo,
este último concatenaria os dois anteriores, e então poderia dar Binding nesta última propriedade.

**Exemplo:**

XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="pckCategoria"
                        Title="Selecione uma Categoria"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoriaCodigo}"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Margin="10, 0, 10, 0">
                </Picker>
```

C#

```
Produto prod = new Produto();
prod.setCodigo(1);
prod.setCategoria("Alimento");
prod.setCategoriaCodigo(string.Format("{0} - {1}", prod.codigo, prod.categoria));
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo bem simples à resposta.

Answer (score -1):

A plataforma Syncfusion tem um componente Picker com múltiplos valores, acredito que é justamente o que procura. Existe uma licença gratuita do Syncfusion para desenvolvedores individuais e pequenas empresas.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/picker

Comment: Procuramos por soluções nativas, agradeço. Caso não seja possível trazer os dois conteúdos no picker eu posso simplesmente receber o Código da Categoria quando uma Categoria for selecionada também, já seria uma saída.